# How to write non-ascii characters in UTF8 xml file from US7ASCII Oracle Database

Tags: xml, oracle, utf-8, plsql, non-ascii-characters

I'm trying to write an XML file encoded in UTF-8 using data from an Oracle 9 database (should also work on Oracle 11) set up with NLS_CHARACTERSET = US7ASCII, NLS_LANGUAGE = AMERICAN.
I use the XMLELEMENT and xmlattributes functions in order to construct a clob, and then I create a file from this clob.

Here's a simple example:

```
declare
xmlval  clob;
begin
    SELECT XMLELEMENT( "Parent", 
      XMLELEMENT( "Address", xmlattributes( unistr( 'N°27' ) as "Street", unistr( '77800' ) as "PostCode", unistr( 'Paris' ) as "City" ) )
         ).extract('/*').getclobVal()
    INTO xmlval
    FROM DUAL;

    dbms_xslprocessor.clob2file( xmlval, 'DIRXMLTMP', 'file.xml', nls_charset_id('AL32UTF8') );
end;
```

The tables in the database can contain several non-ascii characters as the client uses, I think, the Windows 1252 character code set.

Currently, I have to use the unistr function, otherwise, the procedure crashes when a field contains non-ascii characters.

Now, this code can generate the xml files but the non-ascii characters are replaced with the '?' character : 'N°27' becomes 'N?27'.

I've tried to play with the convert function in order to modify the string 'N°27' or the variable xmlval, for example :

```
convert( xmlval, 'WE8MSWIN1252', 'US7ASCII' )
convert( 'N°27', 'US7ASCII', 'WE8MSWIN1252' )
```

But I still get 'N?27' in the resulting file.

Is it possible to display these specific characters in the generated file from a us7ascii database?

Comment: Instead of UNISTR try to use ASCIISTR. It converts national character set to '\xxxx' representation. And UNISTR converts '\xxxx' back to national character set

Comment: Thanks for the tip but, for some reasons, I always get \FFFD for all the different specific characters I've tried : 'éè°' -> '\FFFD\FFFD\FFFD'

Comment: I created some function to encode the special characters in us7ascii similarly to what asciistr is supposed to do, and the corresponding decode function.

Comment: I finally can get my special characters in the clob xmlval! But I haven't managed to write the characters correctly encoded in UTF-8 in the xml file using the dbms_xslprocessor.clob2file function. I can create a correct Win1252 file but each time I try to convert data to UTF-8, all special characters end up encoded as 'EF BF BD'

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I got some workaround:

1- create a function to encode characters above 127 as the string representing the corresponding hexadecimal code surrounded by specific delimiters: encodeSpecialChars('°') -> '#B0#'

2- create the function to decode the encoded strings: decodeSpecialChars('#B0#') -> '°'

3- create the XML clob by filtering all fields

4- decode the clob

5- convert the clob's raw data in UTF-8

6- save the data to a raw file using utl_file and utl_raw packages

```
declare
xmlval  clob;
begin
    SELECT XMLELEMENT( "Address", xmlattributes( encodeSpecialChars( 'N°27' ) as "Street", encodeSpecialChars( 'Frébault' ) as "City" )
         ).extract('/*').getclobVal()
    INTO xmlval
    FROM DUAL;

    -- <Address Street="N#B0#27" City="Fr#E9#bault"/>
    xmlval := decodeSpecialChars( xmlval );
    -- <Address Street="N°27" City="Frébault"/>     -- encoded in Windows-1252

    l_output := utl_file.fopen( 'DIRXMLTMP', 'fff.xml', 'w' );
    utl_file.PUT_RAW( l_output, UTL_RAW.convert( UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW( xmlval ), 'FRENCH_FRANCE.AL32UTF8', 'FRENCH_FRANCE.WE8MSWIN1252' ) ); 
    utl_file.fclose( l_output );
end;
```